# How to show different shopping cart from different User/User Session?

Tags: php, session

I want to display different shopping cart from different user session. Here's the details :

- The customer can add item(s) to the shopping cart even he/she isn't logged in yet or in other word there's no user session ($_SESSION['User']) is set.
- The shipping details form will be displayed if user session
  ($_SESSION['User']) is set. If the customer want a quick shop and fill the shipping details, the customer can click a button to proceed quick shop without logged in. I can done this by myself using this variable below to create user session after the customer pressed the 'proceed' button :

> $_SESSION['User'] = session_id();

I know that the variable above create a random user id to set the user session. After the customer click the 'proceed' button, the system will automatically create user session so the shipping details form will be displayed.

But how if i want to remove Cart's Session if he/she is logged in? Here's some points i know :

- If the user is logged in, the $_SESSION['User'] value is the customer's username.
- But, if the user isn't logged in but have the user session (after clicking the 'proceed' button), the $_SESSION['User'] value is a random string (because i use

> session_id()

function that generate random string to create user session)

The point is, how to remove the cart session from user session (that using random session id) if the user is logged in?

**In other words : **
How to display different shopping cart from different user session?

Thank you.

P.S : Sorry for bad english and my sentences that make you confused

Comment: Why mix the cart and user session? Keep the cart as it's own thing: `$_SESSION['cart] = array(//...items...)`. This way, you can change the user session how much you want, without it affecting the cart at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_SESSION` variable can be used to store the products even if the user is not logged in.

So you can start by creating an array to store the items in the shopping cart:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = [];
}
```

An empty array has now been created to store any products you put into it. You store products in the cart using the product identifier from your database:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = 5; // insert the product with id 5
```

When you want to checkout the cart you can access the customer's cart using `$_SESSION['cart']` and retrieve information about the products using the ids located in the cart.

Hope this helps.